# Cauchy-Riemann: total or partial derivative with respect to $\bar z$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, cauchy-riemann-equations

The Cauchy-Riemann conditions for a function $f$ are respected if:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = 0$$

But is it a partial or a total derivative actually ?

If it is partial, then I can safely say that if $f = f(z)$, then:

$$\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \bar z} = 0 \; \; \; \forall f$$

For instance, $f(z) = \exp(z).\exp(\frac{1}{z})$ would be analytic $\forall z \neq 0$, thus.

Comment: it's of course a partial derivative... Be careful with your $f=f(z)$. Indeed, $f(z)=\bar z$ but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=1$. So, you have to be sure that $f(\bar z,z)=f(z)$.

Comment: It is not a partial derivative, it is a differential operator defined as $\partial_{\overline z}:=\frac 12(\partial_x+i\partial_y)$ (see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives or also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264509/doubt-in-the-complex-form-of-cauchy-riemann-condition)

Comment: Your $f$ is indeed analytic on $\Bbb C^*.$ The function $g:z\mapsto\bar z$ is not. $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}=1.$

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, the question is perfectly stated and is indeed of interest